# onSharedPreferenceChanged without using getDefaultSharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using context.getSharedPreference instead of getDefaultSharedPreferences.
Means :

```
SharedPreferences checkboxSetting = context.getSharedPreferences(
                                         "myPreferenceDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean flag = checkboxSetting.getBoolean("checkboxKey",true);
```

And preference.xml :

```
<CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="checkBoxPrefff"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Application setting has a checkboxpreference that I want to get the value of, checked or not checked.

Will this work?

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                                      String key) {
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("checkBoxPrefff")) { 
         sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,true);
    }
 }
```

Does sharedPreferences use default database ( ..._preference.xml ) or my defined database ( "myPreferenceDB" )?
Does key is "checkboxKey" or is null?

Because when I want to get value like

```
SharedPreferences temp = context.getSharedPreferences(
                                         "myPreferenceDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean flag = temp.getBoolean("checkboxKey",true);
```

it's wrong and gets back defValue (true) . But when use like

```
SharedPreferences temp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean flag = temp.getBoolean("checkboxKey",true);
```

it works.

Comment: "Does sharedPreferences use default database ( ..._preference.xml ) or my defined database ( "myPreferenceDB" )" - it depends on what _you poass to the function_. Also is your key `checkboxKey` or `checkBoxPrefff`. And also `equalsIgnoreCase` ? _equalsIgnoreCase_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I would like to mention sharedPref is not a DB but rather an XML file. I hope you are looking for the following code.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.preference.PreferenceActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("myPref"); 
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,but sharedPreferences are DB ,typical.by the way,getPreferenceManager is deprecated . what's instead of?

Comment: 2-If i use setSharedPreferencesName and change default name,no need to  add values manually (ex : myPrefIns.edit().putString("myKey",valueeee).commit()) ?

Comment: getPreferenceManager() is deprecated from API11. You simply want to have a settings like screen and wish to store the values in the shared pref then you don't need to manually save it.  Also see- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html, I you wish to store values from anywhere else like any other activity/service, etc you have to do it manually.

Comment: Yes,i know it's deprecated from 11,and i set minSdkVErsion to 5 .So what's happen?

Comment: Nothing. Did you try implement this ?

Comment: Yes,i use it.i just wanted to know what's happen in 11+.Nothing?! :-o so why document says it's deprecated?!

Comment: The reason for deprecation is specified as "This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity. " Since your minSDKVersion is 5 you can go ahead and use this. You will not face any problem

Answer (score 1):

You can register a SharedPreferenceChangedListener on any shared pref that you are using. It need not be the default shared preference.

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPreferenceDB", 0).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks,but it's not my related answer! i want to know does sharedPreferences use default database or my defined database?

Comment: What's different between onPreferenceChange and onSharedPreferenceChanged?

Comment: sharedPref is an xml file which is stored under /data/data/<package-name>/files directory. Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to use my own sharedPref ( not default name ) and don't write any thing for insert values to it ( edit().commit() ) , and just use addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); that handle all insert and update of values to database