# How to change default name of preferences.xml database?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to use `getSharedPreference` instead of `getDefaultSharedPreference` ( because of some bug in some devices [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences)).

And I want to listen to preference changes. So I did something like:

```
this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefDB", MODE_PRIVATE).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key)
        {
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("myPrefKey"))
                {
                  flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,true);
                }
        }
    });
```

But it does not work and give me wrong preference.
Even write something like:

```
public class Setting extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
//like above
}
```

Doesn't work again.
I should say I don't write anything for insert value(`edit()`, `commit()`). I just use:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

And I think this above line write the value to default database name(like "`com.example.something_preferences`"). But I want to write values to my custom name (myPrefDB).

Comment: "because of some bug in second in some devices" -- citation, please.

Comment: @CommonsWare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set shared preference name in PreferenceActivity, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286822/onsharedpreferencechanged-without-using-getdefaultsharedpreferences):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.preference.PreferenceActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("myPref"); 
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
}
```

And for use SharedPreference in every where else:

```
SharedPreferences prf = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedpreferenceNAMEthatYOUwant", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (`SharedPreferences.edit()`) and then commit changes (`Editor.commit()`).